# Calculating sample size

Tags: statistics

A city Humane Society wishes to determine the life expectancy of adopted dogs from their shelter.

How many of the dog owners do they need to contact in order to be 90% confident of being within 0.29 of the true mean life expectancy? A preliminary survey indicates that the ages are approximately normally distributed with a standard deviation of 1.9.

I've interpreted this question for the following variables:

$$\sigma = 1.9\\
z_c = 1.645\\
E = 0.29$$

And using the below formula:

$$\begin{align}
    n & = (\frac{z_c\sigma}{E})^2 \\
      & = (\frac{(1.645)(1.9)}{0.29})^2 \\
      & \approx (10.78)^2 \\
    n & \approx 116.2
  \end{align}$$

This is incorrect, however. Why? Is this the incorrect formula to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I see it, you have a confidence interval:

$(\mu-(1.645)(1.9)/(n)^{1/2}, \mu+(1.645)(1.9)/(n)^{1/2}   $, and you want

the radius of the interval to be 0.29